# malloc checkpoints

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I am sure someone must have implemented something like this already!
What I am looking for is the ability to "checkpoint" the heap state and then clear all allocations that have happened since the last checkpoint.
Basically what I am looking for is a natural corollary of the _CrtMemCheck Apis.

Something like(preferably cross-platform)

```
//we save the heap state here in s1
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &s1 );

//allocs and frees

//Get rid of all allocs since checkpoint s1 that have not been freed!
_CrtMemClearAllObjectsSince(&s1);
```

Comment: Can you not store current time to set the checkpoint, and then track the pointers that you have got from malloc since then, perhaps in an array?Or is it that that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: Problem is I am using a third party library that is leaking memory, causing memory fragmentation and eventually out of memory  condition for me. But the good news is that i control the linking. :) So I need someway to link in my custom malloc/free and a eventual freeall. :)

Comment: I would 1) press for the library owner to fix it.  2) failing that, put that third party library in an executable separate from your main code and just kill and relaunch that process periodically.  3) if on a single process OS, I'd find a better library.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to use mark/release memory allocation in C.  If you know for a fact that all `malloc`/`free calls will be used in a LIFO fashion, you may be able to link in your own`malloc`/`free` functions using something like the following:

```
#define MY_HEAP_SIZE 12345678
unsigned char my_mem[MY_HEAP_SIZE];
unsigned char *my_alloc_ptr = my_mem;

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
  void *ret = my_alloc_ptr;
  if (size <= MY_HEAP_SIZE && ((my_alloc_ptr - my_mem)+size) <= MY_HEAP_SIZE)
  {
    my_alloc_ptr += size;
    return (void*)ret;
  }
  else
    return (void*)0;
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
  if (ptr)
    my_alloc_ptr = ptr;
}
```

This approach requires zero bytes of overhead per allocation block, but calling `free()` on any block will also free all blocks that were allocated later.  An alternative approach which could be used if the external code doesn't use `malloc/free` in LIFO order, but it would be okay if blocks don't freed until your code does so, would be to make `free()` do nothing, but have some other function which behaves like `free` above.  More sophisticated variations are possible as well, but in cases where the first approach will suffice, there's no beating its efficiency.  Very nice for embedded systems (though I'd usually call it something other than malloc).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify malloc()/free() using [hooks](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) to remember allocated memory (for example, suppose that your record the new pointer in an array of pointers). Then your can have two functions:

- `int get_checkpoint()`, that returns the next free array index,
- `void free_until(int checkpoint)`, that frees memory from the current stored pointer in the array backwards, until `checkpoint` is reached.

This way, you can do:

```
int cpoint = get_checkpoint();
LibraryDoSomething();
free_until(cpoint);
```

Of course, this technique is still dangerous; calling a C library function can have side effects that you can easily affect. The best advice is still that of Amardeep.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible and interesting solution could be the use of LD_PRELOAD. As the man page for LD_PRELOAD states "This can be used to selectively override functions in other shared libraries."

Thus, you can have your own implementations of malloc and free wherein you can implement the required checks and then call the default malloc or free.

You can check the details here: http://somethingswhichidintknow.blogspot.com/2009/10/dll-injection.html